# Will a chain of javascript objects pointing to null be garbage collected?

Tags: javascript, performance, garbage-collection

I'm just doing some experiments with scoping in javascript.
My question: In the following code snippet, will 'second' and 'third' be garbage collected? This could be of particular use when dealing with linked lists.

```
var first = {}
var second = first;
var third = second;

first = null;
```

Comment: short answer: yes. Can you guess why?

Comment: The object is still available through second and third, so no, it doesn't get GC.

Comment: @JanDvorak - That isn't right. The object still has live references as long as `second` and `third` are still in scope somewhere (even if just in a closure).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.   `second` and `third` still have references to your object so it cannot yet be garbage collected.

When you do this:

```
var first = {};
var second = first;
```

Your variable `second` does not have a reference to `first`.  It has a reference to the same object that `first` points to.  So, now you have two equal variables that both have a reference to the same object.

When you set:

```
 first = null;
```

All, you did was clear the reference to that object in the `first` variable.  The object itself was not affected at all.  And, most importantly to your question, the variable `second` was not affected at all so it still has a reference to that object and thus it cannot be garbage collected.

For an object in Javascript to be garbage collected, there must be no live references to that object anywhere in the code that are in reachable code.  As long as `second` is still a reachable variable, the object it points to cannot be garbage collected.

---

If you know a language like C++ with pointers, then you can think of an assignment like you did in

```
var first = {};
```

like putting a pointer to your object into `first`.  `first` doesn't actually contain the object itself.  The object exists on its own.  `first` just contains a point to that object.

Then, when you do:

```
var second = first;
```

You create another variable and you get the pointer from `first` and put a copy of that same point into `second`.  Now you have two completely separate variables that both contain a pointer to your object.  Remember, the object exists on it's own so when you then do:

```
first = null;
```

All you are doing is clearing the pointer in `first`.  The object is still there and `second` still contains a pointer to it.   Since there's still a live pointer to it, the object will not be garbage collected.

---

For your object to be garbage collected, you would either need all three variables that contain a reference to the object to be cleared as in:

```
var first = {}
var second = first;
var third = second;

first = null;
second = null;
third = null;
```

Or, you would need all three variables to go out of scope so the variables themselves got garbage collected.

Comment: MDN mentions an older 'reference counting' algorithm and a newer 'mark and sweep'. Does the algorithm matter in terms of reference to the object? [Memory Management](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management)

Comment: @Duco - Those are just implementation methods that a garbage collector might use to keep track of live references.  The objective behind the garbage collection is the same either way.  Good, reliable and fast garbage collectors are not easy, especially when the number of objects gets large and the relationships between them get complicated and when you want to be able to collect partial scopes and not have any circular reference issues.  Add to this that a browser has two object spaces to collect (Javascript and DOM) and they can be interrelated when Javascript has references to DOM objects).